# control in control losing textBox value   -   probably because of repeater

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a problem: I have a user control in which there is a nested second user control. In that second control I have a textBox.  During postback the value of the textbox is always the same (default one), even if I change text in that textBox.

Is this a common problem?

I just noticed that it might me caused bye repeater cause textBox is inside repater. Do you know how to foce textBox to keep value beetween postbacks if its in repeater ?

Comment: Have you checked that the viewstate is enabled on the textbox/usercontrol?

Comment: How can I do that? Ive never had problems with such a situation

Comment: Ive set EnableViewState = "true" still doesnt work :/

Comment: Is the nested UserControl or TextBox added dynamically?

Comment: UserControl is nested in another userControl

Comment: Can you post your code on how your assigning your default value, you could be setting them to default on Post Back.  Also, if you have disabled viewstate on repeater/textbox, this could also be a problem.  Showing code would help everybody provide a better answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is not the problem, it is in your code. I guess your value is repopulating the old one in the `Page_load` event of the usercontrol.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not a common issue.   You should check where the control is being added and were the default value is being set.  Either one could be causing you troubles.